# How to convert hexadecimal hash into binary at terminal?

Tags: openssl, binaryfiles, hexdump, xxd

Main question: **How to use `xxd -r`?**

Secondary details. This command outputs a hexadecimal hash:

```sh
openssl dgst -sha256 myFile |  awk '{print $2}' > myHashHex
```

I suppose that `myHashHex` is a "hexdump", isn't it? 
I thought that `xxd -r < myHashHex` will convert...  Well, **it does not work**.

---

### NOTES

To test/compare. I think that this is the same (no headers) in binary:

```sh
openssl dgst -sha256 -binary myFile > myHashBin
```

So, I expected that `xxd -r < myHashHex > newHashBin` generates *newHashBin*=*myHashBin*.

---

PS: to **test**. The real life problem is to maintain all with sha256sum and only in one procedure convert it to double-sha256.

Instead, I use `openssl dgst -sha256 -binary myFile| openssl dgst -sha256 > myDoubleHash` 
I would use the two-step procedure:

1. (always produce myHashHex) 
   `openssl dgst -sha256 myFile |  awk '{print $2}' > myHashHex`
2. (when need double) `xxd -r myHashHex | openssl dgst -sha256 > myDoubleHash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Types of Hexdumps

The problem is that xxd expects a formatted hexdump, but you are sending in a string of hex numbers. This is what xxd refers to as a "plain hexdump".

A formatted hexdump looks like this (quote by Joseph Campbell):

```sh
$ printf "Computers are like old testament gods; lots of rules and no mercy." | xxd
00000000: 436f 6d70 7574 6572 7320 6172 6520 6c69  Computers are li
00000010: 6b65 206f 6c64 2074 6573 7461 6d65 6e74  ke old testament
00000020: 2067 6f64 733b 206c 6f74 7320 6f66 2072   gods; lots of r
00000030: 756c 6573 2061 6e64 206e 6f20 6d65 7263  ules and no merc
00000040: 792e                                     y.
```

xxd will, by default, create this kind of hexdump.

### Use -p for hex strings

Per the [xxd manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd), `-r` expects to read a formatted hexdump:

```
-r | -revert
    reverse operation: ... 
    Use the combination -r -p to read plain hexadecimal 
    dumps without line number information and without a particular column layout. 
    ...
```

To reiterate, by default, `xxd -r` expects a formatted hexdump. To read or write a "plain hexdump" with xxd, use the `-p` option. Note that xxd expects flags to come before arguments, so if you end with a flag, you will get unexpected behavior.

## Verification

If you can see that running openssl twice (initially with `-binary`) and running openssl with xxd produce the same result.

```sh
$ openssl dgst -sha256 <( printf "Hello World!" ) |  awk '{print $2}' > myHashHex; 
$ xxd -r -p myHashHex | openssl dgst -sha256 
(stdin)= 61f417374f4400b47dcae1a8f402d4f4dacf455a0442a06aa455a447b0d4e170
$ openssl dgst -sha256 -binary <( printf "Hello World!" ) | openssl dgst -sha256
(stdin)= 61f417374f4400b47dcae1a8f402d4f4dacf455a0442a06aa455a447b0d4e170
```